# What does the word “trip” exactly mean in English?

Tags: meaning, nouns

My question is whether “trip” means experiences on the way to one’s destination or experiences after arriving at the destination? Or can it mean both?

Comment: The auxiliary in your question is "does", and have you looked up the word, trip, in a dictionary? What did it say?

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Mari. I have looked up the word in two dictionaries, but they only say that "trip" can be replaced by "journey".

Comment: A trip is usually a short journey to a destination and its return. If one asks: *Did you have a good trip?* The person is usually asking if your journey was pleasant one. You can go on a business trip, or for pleasure. You might say: *"My trip to Naples was unforgettable"* meaning the journey but also your stay in Naples was very pleasurable. (I hope this helps you) If you want to reopen your question you need to add more information/context and say why you don't understand.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's "on-the-way experiences". It actually means "journey" or "excursion", but from the two options given, it definitely means "on the way to one's destination".